# Issue uploading to Firebase Storage using cloud functions with Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

So basically what I am trying to do is download a .txt file, add some text to it and reupload it back to firebase cloud storage.

The original contents of the file are apples, pears, and oranges. After downloading the file and adding a new line of text to it. It should say apples, pears, oranges, exiting early.

When I use the default security rules I get

> error: {
>     code: 403
>     message: "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
>   }

The code that I am using to upload this file looks like this ( its written in typescript btw)

With the following code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');admin.initializeApp(functions.config().dbconfig);

const fileName = 'filecopy.txt'
const destination = 'text/filecopy.txt'
const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName)
console.log( `Writing out to ${tempFilePath}`)

const bucketRef = admin.storage().bucket(functions.config().dbconfig.storage_bucket);


bucketRef.file(`text/filecopy.txt`).download(function (error, contents) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(contents.toString())
    console.log(contents.toString().concat("\nexiting early"))
    fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, contents.toString().concat("exiting early") )

    bucketRef.upload(tempFilePath, {
         destination,
         metadata: {
            contentType: 'text/plain',

        }
        })
    .then( () => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath) )
    .catch(err => console.error('ERROR inside upload: ', err) );
})
```

The one weird thing is that this code works, but only if I change from the default security rules

```
 service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

To security rules where read and write are allowed by anyone which I would rather not have... I have been working on this all day and haven't really found a solution is there anyway anybody can help?

Comment: The Admin SDK (and any server SDK initialized by a service account) is not affected by security rules at all when it works with Cloud Storage, so that's not the issue here.  What exactly is `tempFilePath`?

Comment: please post your security rules

Comment: @DougStevenson see updated code

Comment: @SushantSomani the default security rules are my current security rules